# ImageDataGenerator on Google Colab runs Forever

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I am running a simple image classification problem on google colab with keras. To increase the size of my training data i'm using `ImageDataGenerator`.

When I run the following code below on my local computer, it run just fine with no problem. However, when I run it on google colab it seems to run indefinitely.

```
augmented_history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, 
                                                     y_train_wide, 
                                                     batch_size=32),
                                        epochs=15,
                                        validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid_wide),
                                        callbacks=[es, mc])
```

On google colab, It prints the following to the console.

```
Epoch 1/15
   30514/Unknown - 85s 44ms/step - loss: 0.0245 - accuracy: 0.9834
```

It seems to never stop.

Answer (score 0):

Add try to add two parameters **steps_per_epoch** and **validation_steps** to the **fit_generator** call:

```
steps_per_epoch = train_samples // batch_size 
validation_steps = train_samples // batch_size
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keras-fit-and-keras-fit_generator/

> **steps_per_epoch** : it specifies the total number of steps taken from the generator as soon as one epoch is finished and next epoch has
> started. We can calculate the value of steps_per_epoch as the total
> number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size.
>
> **validation_steps** :only if the validation_data is a generator then only this argument can be used. It specifies the total number of steps
> taken from the generator before it is  stopped at every epoch and its
> value is calculated as the total number of validation data points in
> your dataset divided by the validation batch size.